# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of a product

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $R = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ the polynomial ring, $\mathfrak m = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $M$ a finitely generated graded $R$-module. How can we see that 
$\operatorname{reg}(\mathfrak mM) \le \operatorname{reg}(M) + 1$, where $\operatorname{reg}(\cdot)$ denotes Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity?

Remark: i can see that $\operatorname{reg}(\mathfrak m)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $M/\mathfrak mM$ is an $R$-module of finite length, $\operatorname{reg}(M/\mathfrak mM)=\max\{i:(M/\mathfrak mM)_i\ne 0\}$; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109139/castelnuovo-mumford-regularity-and-degree-of-generator). Now, since $\operatorname{reg}(M)\ge\max\{j:\beta_{0j}(M)\ne 0\}$, it follows that $\operatorname{reg}(M)\ge \operatorname{reg}(M/\mathfrak mM)$.